# Error in R filter code, when grouping by month and filtering by year

Tags: r

For whatever reason, when I use my filter function from dplyr I get an obnoxious error despite it working previously in my code.

**Error Below:**

```
Error in `filter()`:
ℹ In argument: `Salesdata`.
ℹ In group 1: `Month = "April"`.
Caused by error:
! `..1` must be of size 3283 or 1, not size 34867.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

**The code I ran was:**

```
df <- 
  Salesdata %>% 
  group_by(Month) %>% 
  filter(Salesdata, Year == 2015) %>% 
  summarise(sum(Revenue))
```

*the data set I'm using comes from:*
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/abhishekrp1517/sales-data-for-economic-data-analysis?resource=download

An in-depth response would be GREATLY appreciated mates!

*I've tried:*

```
dplyr::filter
filter %in%
```

Comment: Remove `Salesdata` from your `filter()` call. Since you’re using the pipe (`%>%`), `Salesdata` is already passed as the first argument to `filter()`, so you shouldn’t be specifying it again.

Comment: Wrong syntax for usage of `filter()`, the `.data` argument (which is the first argument for almost all functions from `dplyr`) is already piped in from the pipe chain. So try `filter(Year == 2015) %>% ` for the fourth line.

Comment: @zephryl & Su Na, thank you guys so much, I did not realize that I needed to remove the df from the filter. Thanks again!